# Compare two tables and show the value of another table if exist, if not exist just show status in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables to compare in SQL. When the `id` from one exists in the other, the result I want is the value of data from the second table; when it doesn't exist it will show "Data not Exist" in the 'value' field name.

Example

Table 1

```
| id|
-----
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
| 10|
```

Table 2

```
|id | value
---------
| 1 | 10|
| 2 | 9 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 8 |    
| 5 | 6 |
```

I've tried the query below:

```
select a.id,
       CASE when exists(select a.id from table2 b where a.id = b.id)
            THEN value
            else 'Data Not Exist'
       END as Result_Value
from table1 a inner join table2 b 
on a.id=b.id
order by a.id;
```

The Result is:

```
|id | Result_Value
---------
| 1 | 10|
| 2 | 9 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 8 |    
| 5 | 6 |
```

Above result that's not I wanted, my expectation result like below:

```
|id | Result_Value
---------
| 1 | 10             |
| 2 | 9              |
| 3 | 7              |
| 4 | 8              |    
| 5 | 6              |
| 6 | Data Not Exist |
| 7 | Data Not Exist |
| 8 | Data Not Exist |
| 9 | Data Not Exist |
| 10| Data Not Exist |
```

Note: This is simple explanation from my query, because my query have complexity to join another table with inner join, I don't know where I'm exactly wrong using select exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `LEFT JOIN`, and [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) any `NULL` values to `Data not Exist`:

```
SELECT a.id, COALESCE(b.value, 'Data not exist') AS value
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = a.id
```

Output:

```
id  value
1   10
2   9
3   7
4   8
5   Data not exist
6   Data not exist
7   Data not exist
8   Data not exist
9   Data not exist
10  Data not exist
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mV92MzhUbM1cpo8XtDy5xN/0)

Comment: Hi Nick, you nailed it. Thanks for your query. Is near what I want. But it seems, 'Data not Exist' cant convert to float, show "Error converting data type varchar to float".

Comment: @agnanzakariya without seeing your entire query and table structure it's hard to be sure, but you might need to leave the values as `NULL` and then `COALESCE` them at the very top of the query

Comment: Solving the error,  i will use `(b.value, '')`. It's more than enough, thanks again Nick

Comment: @agnanzakariya I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 issues here.

1. Don't use `join/inner join` if you want your next table to show up.
2. DataTypes of your `select case` values should be the same.

Here's your query.

```
select a.id,
    case
    when isnull(b.id, '') != ''
        then cast(b.value as varchar(50))
    else
        'Data Not Exist'
    END as Result_Value
from table1 a 
left join table2 b on a.id=b.id
order by a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, Using `LEFT JOIN` between `Table1` and `Table2` and `ISNULL` to check `NULL`, If `NULL` then replace with `Data not Exist`

```
SELECT a.id, ISNULL(b.value,'Data not Exist') AS value FROM dbo.Table1 a 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 b ON a.id=b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired results by using a `LEFT JOIN` a long side with one of:

- `COALESCE()` expression.
- `ISNULL()` function.
- `CASE` expression.
- `IIF()` function.

As the following

```
SELECT T1.Id,
       COALESCE(CAST(T2.Value AS VARCHAR(10)), 'Data Not Exist') ByCoalesce,
       ISNULL(CAST(T2.Value AS VARCHAR(10)), 'Data Not Exist') ByIsNull,
       CASE WHEN T2.Value IS NULL
            THEN 'Data Not Exist'
            ELSE CAST(T2.Value AS VARCHAR(10))
       END ByCaseExpression,
       IIF(T2.Value IS NULL, 'Data Not Exist', CAST(T2.Value AS VARCHAR(10))) ByIifFunction
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (1),
  (2),
  (3),
  (4),
  (5),
  (6),
  (7),
  (8),
  (9),
  (10)
) T1(Id) LEFT JOIN
(
  VALUES
  (1, 10),
  (2, 9 ),
  (3, 7 ),
  (4, 8 ),    
  (5, 6 )
) T2(Id, Value)
ON T1.Id = T2.Id;
```

Note that you need to `CAST() / CONVERT()` the `INT` values to `VARCHAR(n)` because `VARCHAR` data type has a lower **[precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** than `INT` data type.

**[Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b5eccab178886b769c00f9eb2a2efdde)**